# Javascript find-and-replace special characters

Tags: javascript

I have a string that may contain an apostrophe (') or an ampersand (&). I need to find if either one or both exists. If they do, then replace them with `'&apos;` and/or `'&amp;`

```
trim(Pos_Query_Super.replace(/'/g,"'&apos;"))
```

Can I add an and/or condition to the above and simply replace it using javascript? This development is in an process flow IDE were we can use JS expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a function to return the replacement based on the match

```
trim(Pos_Query_Super.replace(/'|&/g,function(match){
    return {
            '\'':'\'&apos;', 
            '&':'\'&amp;'
           }[match]
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not do your own HTML-escape mapping. Instead, use DOM routines to do that:

```js
function HtmlEscape(str) {
  const s = document.createElement('span');
  s.textContent = str;
  return s.innerHTML;
}

console.log(HtmlEscape("foo'bar&baz<div>Bob</div>"));
```

You will note that this does not escape the single quote--because there is no reason to do so.

Comment: "because there is no reason to do so" --- how do you know it?

Comment: How do you know that there is?

Comment: I don't know - I trust OPs until proven otherwise :-)